# Download link excel in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

In controller laravel: I use box/spout , I save the excel file in a separate folder, and i create a variable that points to the folder where the file is saved, and i return the vuejs view to download that file

```
$path = '/files/'.$name;
$urlFile = url('/files/'.$name);
var_dump($urlFile);
// Result:
http://localhost.loca/file/data.xlsx
```

I return view vuejs:

```
return response()->json($urlFile);
```

View vuejs :

```
    methods: {
      // event button click
      clickButton() {
        axios
        .get("/api/export")
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data) // http://localhost.loca/file/data.xlsx
         // I want to download this link !
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
       }
     }
```

Please give me idea download link ? Thanks

**Update**: I use `window.open(res.data)` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an anchor and click on it programmatically to download the file :

```
.then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data) // http://localhost.loca/file/data.xlsx
  //create and append anchor download to body
  const downloadAnchor = document.createElement("a");
  downloadAnchor.setAttribute("href", "http://localhost.loca/file/data.xlsx");
  downloadAnchor.setAttribute("download", "data.xlsx");
  document.body.appendChild(downloadAnchor);
  downloadAnchor.click();
  //remove anchor download
  document.body.removeChild(downloadAnchor);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If `window.open` doesn't work you can try this:

```js
function download(url) {
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = url
  a.download = url.split('/').pop()
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  document.body.removeChild(a)
}
```

And then call the download function in your method:

```js
    methods: {
      // event button click
      clickButton() {
        axios
        .get("/api/export")
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data) // http://localhost.loca/file/data.xlsx
          download(res.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I downloaded it, but for some reason, when I open the excel file, it says `"Excel cannot open the file"`. But the original excel file can still be opened